# .Net core tcp listener windows hosting options

Tags: c#, sockets, asp.net-core, tcp, .net-core

I create a tcp server in .net core with the TcpListener class. I used the following tutorial: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-a-tcp-server-in-net-core-on-ubuntu/.

Now what are my hosting options for the .net core tcp server? As far as I understood I can host the tcp server only as a windows service. Is it also possible to host the tcp server in iis?

Comment: The term "SERVER" as lots of different meanings.   A TCP connection has a Client and a Server which is what the code in the link uses.  A TCP Server is not usually a SERVICE.  You can include in a SERVICE a TCP server.  See blog : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/james_osbornes_blog/2010/12/07/hosting-in-iis-using-nettcpbinding/

Comment: IIS TCP support was designed for WCF ("net.tcp") so it is not something arbitrary for all TCP scenarios. Windows services would be good hosts, and you can also use console applications.